# Add external libraries in SPFx?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript, react

How to add external libraries like `material-ui` to our Spfx Webpart?

I know to add external libraries having their CDN link and types definition like jquery but don't know how to add libraries which have their type definition but do not have CDN link like `material-ui`.

Please tell if anybody had worked on such libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could enable CDN for your Office 365 tenant so you could upload  your JS library to SharePoint online and load from it.

Below sample list steps to enable CDN for Office 365 tenant.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn

Or, another approach like below sample.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom

Update:

Sample test with material ui(I'm not familiar with material ui currently, but it's based on React DOM, so I use React as my SPFx framework and insatall material ui by npm, seems working, when bundle the assets, the script will be 'translate' to javascript).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you have not understood the question just follow this link to add external libraries [link]( http://ericoverfield.com/spfx-101-include-an-additional-typings-definition-in-your-spfx-project-using-types/ ) here in config.json in externals we add  cdn of jquery , my question is what if we don't have any cdn link like that of material-ui library

Comment: You may check my update

Answer (score 0):

To install: npm install material-ui

To install types: npm i @types/material-ui

To use: Lee_MSFT is doing it correctly and there IS NO CDN referenced for types as you can see he's using in his example the package from NPM.

IF YOU purely want the types then Google 'npm' + library name + 'types', library name is the only dynamic thing here so your search will look like so: **npm material-ui types**

So in short use CDN links: https://jquery.css etc

OR

use packages e.g.: npm install jquery @jquery-types

Using both at the same time for same library can make you confused.